# Serialize XmlAttribute which is an empty string

Tags: c#, xml, string, serialization, xml-attribute

I got a class which represents a soccerplayer:

```
public class PlayerExtended
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")] public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("shortName")] public string ShortName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("firstName")] public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("surName")] public string SurName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("shirtNumber")] public string ShirtNumber { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("actions")] public string Actions { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("substitude")] public string Substitude { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("grade")] public string Grade { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("iconSmall")] public string IconSmall { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("position")] public string Position { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("squadPositionID")] public string SquadPositionId { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("squadPosition")] public string SquadPosition { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("inMinute")] public string InMinute { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("outMinute")] public string OutMinute { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("captain")] public string Captain { get; set; }
}
```

After assigning values to the properties one of the players looks like this:

[image: playerModel]
The property "Actions" is an empty string (NOT NULL).

If I serialize it it looks like this:

```
<player id="51641" shortName="Bürki" firstName="Roman" surName="Bürki" shirtNumber="1" substitude="starter" grade="2,5" iconSmall="xxx.whatever.com" position="11" squadPositionID="1" squadPosition="Torwart"/>
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
<player id="51641" shortName="Bürki" firstName="Roman" surName="Bürki" shirtNumber="1" actions="" substitude="starter" grade="2,5" iconSmall="xxx.whatever.com" position="11" squadPositionID="1" squadPosition="Torwart"/>
```

So how do I serialize an XmlAttribute which is an empty string?

Comment: Did you already try putting `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]` attribute instead of XmlAttribute ?  Did it work ?

Comment: Yes it "works" .. but it looks like this:

Comment: <player id="51641" shortName="Bürki" firstName="Roman" surName="Bürki" shirtNumber="1" substitude="starter" grade="2,5" iconSmall="xxx.whatever.com" position="11" squadPositionID="1" squadPosition="Torwart">
<Actions/>
</player>

Comment: not what I want

Comment: @ManojChoudhari XmlElement is not the same as an XmlAttribute, this won't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serialize string property as attribute, even if string is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835102/serialize-string-property-as-attribute-even-if-string-is-empty)

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Given `var player = new PlayerExtended { Id = "51641", Actions = "", };` the XML I am getting is `<PlayerExtended id="51641" actions="" />`.  See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mfWs4i  Can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing how you generated the XML?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari - OP states that *"Actions" is an empty string (NOT NULL)* so I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: Can't reproduce on .NET Core 3.1.0 https://dotnetfiddle.net/mfWs4i or .NET Framework 4.7 https://dotnetfiddle.net/2WRvvP

Answer (score 1):

How are you generating your XML? I cannot seem to reproduce your issue.

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var writer = new StringWriter();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Player));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, new Player { Name = "", Age = 25 });
            Console.WriteLine(writer);
        }
    }

    public class Player
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        [XmlAttribute("age")]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

The code above results in the name attribute in the format you desire (`name=""`). Let me know if this answer is sufficient for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

// Runtime Target = .NET Core v2.1 or .NET Core v3.1

namespace XmlSerialize
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mickey = new Employee { FirstName = "Mickey", LastName = "Mouse" };
            var asterix = new Employee { FirstName = "Asterix", LastName = "" };
            var obelix = new Employee { FirstName = "Obelix", LastName = null };
            var nixnix = new Employee { FirstName = null, LastName = null };

            Console.WriteLine(SerializeXml(mickey) + SerializeXml(asterix) + SerializeXml(obelix) + SerializeXml(nixnix));
        }

        public static string SerializeXml<T>(T instanceToSerialize)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(instanceToSerialize.GetType(), string.Empty);
            var result = string.Empty;
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, instanceToSerialize);
                result = stringWriter.ToString();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Employee")]
    public sealed class Employee
    {
        [XmlAttribute("FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("LastName")]
        public string SerializableLastName // <------------ Might this help?
        {
            get { return this.LastName ?? string.Empty; }
            set { this.LastName = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement]
        public List<string> Skills { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Employee FirstName="Mickey" LastName="Mouse" />
<Employee FirstName="Asterix" LastName="" />
<Employee FirstName="Obelix" LastName="" />
<Employee LastName="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

setting the property value to `string.Empty` will do the trick. I am using `XmlSerializer` to convert the object to XML. If I set the property to `string.Empty`, this will result as empty attribute in XML. Here is the example

```
public class TestClass
{
    [XmlAttribute("test1")]
    public string test1 { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("test2")]
    public string test2 { get; set; }
}

var dd = new List<TestClass>();

dd.Add( new TestClass() { test1 = "asdf", test2 = string.Empty }); //will generate empty attribute for test2
dd.Add( new TestClass() { test1 = "asdf" }); //the attribute test2 will be ignored

using (var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
{
   var serializer = new XmlSerializer(dd.GetType());

   serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, dd);
   Console.WriteLine( stringwriter.ToString());
}
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfTestClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <TestClass test1="asdf" test2="" />
 <TestClass test1="asdf" />
</ArrayOfTestClass>
```

Comment: His example is already showing he's using an empty string

Comment: @Timmeh, the above example shows if you use `XmlSerializer` you get the desired result

Comment: I had already answered that 8 minutes prior?

Comment: Perfect @Timmeh. upvoted your post

Comment: I don't know if XmlSerializer is a solution for the questioner :shrug:, guess he'll have to comment if he even returns to the website.